# R: sparse.model.matrix(), but don't convert a specific variable to dummy variables

Tags: r

I have a variable, `var1` with 12 distinct integers in the domain of `[1, 12]`. It is a `char` type field. How do I make it so `sparse.model.matrix` skips `var1` when converting variables to dummies?

```
X_train_sparse <- sparse.model.matrix(y_var ~ .-1, data = X_train)[,-1]
```

I tried to convert `var1` to numeric but that didn't work. It still gets broken up into 12 distinct variables, one for each level.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can drop var1 column before conversion and pass the updated train data:   `train1<- train %>% dplyr::select(-var1)`

Comment: How do I add it back after sparse model matrix? I need it in the final model.